# Indexing affects only the WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

If I have something like:

```
CREATE INDEX   idx_myTable_field_x
ON             myTable
USING          btree (field_x);

SELECT COUNT(field_x), field_x FROM myTable GROUP BY field_x ORDER BY field_x;
```

Imagine `myTable` with around `500,000 rows` and most of `field_x` values being unique.

Since I don't use any `WHERE` clause, will the created index have any effect at all in my query?

**Edit**: I'm asking this question because I don't get any relevant difference between query-times before and after creating the index; They always take about 8 seconds (which, of course is too much time!). Is this behaviour expected?

Comment: If completely wrong answers are upvoted up to 2.5 times more than the only right one I think the voting system is fundamentally broken. :-(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The index will not help here as you are reading the whole table anyway there is no use in going to an index first (PostgreSQL does not yet have index-only scans)

Because nearly all values in the index are unique, it wouldn't really help in this situation anyway. Index lookups (including index-scans for other DBMS) tend to be really helpful for lookup of a small number of rows.

There is a slight possibility that the index might be used for ordering but I doubt that.

If you look at the output of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE VERBOSE` you can see if the sorting is done in memory or (due to the size of the result) is done on disk.

If sorting is done on disk, you can speed up the query by increasing the work_mem - either globally or just for your session.

Comment: Thanks, that's really useful information; This is a public query executed by a large audience therefore I'm not sure increasing work_mem is a good option, what do you think?

Comment: Increasing work_mem globally might not be a good idea if you have many connections. But you can increase it for just that single statement (using `SET work_mem = ...`). But you should first check if the sort is indeed done on disk

Comment: Thank you for your precious help. The sort is indeed done on disk `Sort Method: external merge Disk: 4984kB`; However, after `SET work_mem = '6000'`, the query seems to take just as long as it did before, 8 seconds which is unacceptable :-(...

Comment: @Andre: Did you check the plan after setting work_mem? The default is 16MB, so with `work_mem = '6000'` you actually reduced it. And maybe it needs more than what is shown in the logfile. You should try something like `work_mem = '20MB'` to go beyond the default.

Comment: You are right (I was mislead by http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/runtime-config-resource.html that states default value is `1MB`) after setting it to `20MB` the query time actually was reduced a little (not enough though); Thanks, you helped a lot! :)

Answer (score 3):

Since `field_x` is the only column referenced in your query, your index [covers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_%28database%29#Covering_Index) the query and should help you avoid lookups into actual rows of `myTable`.

**EDIT**: As indicated in the comment discussion below, while this answer is valid for most RDBMS implementations, it does not apply to postgresql.

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli, Thanks; (as updated) I'm asking this question because I don't get any relevant difference between query-times before and after creating the index; They always take about 8 seconds (which, of course is too much time!). Is this behaviour expected?

Comment: @andre matos: Do you know if the index is being used when it exists? What does the output of EXPLAIN show?

Comment: @Joe: unfortunately Postgres does not (yet) have index-only scans. A "table lookup" is always needed in Postgres

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli,  
GroupAggregate  (cost=46675.90..52671.15 rows=299620 width=7)
  `->  Sort  (cost=46675.90..47425.90 rows=300000 width=7)`
        Sort Key: field_x | 
        `->  Seq Scan on mytable  (cost=0.00..15282.00 rows=300000 width=7)`

Comment: @andre matos: That output makes sense in light of @a_horse_with_no_name's previous comment. So, for postgresql, the index will not help in this specific instance.

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli, Do you suggest any approach then? 8 seconds is a life time! :-)

Answer (score 2):

The index should be used.  If you ever want to see how your indexes are being used (or not), the execution plan of the query is a great place to see what the database has decided to do.  In your case you should execute something like:

```
explain SELECT COUNT(field_x), field_x FROM myTable GROUP BY field_x ORDER BY field_x;
```

More information about what all the output you are seeing means can be found in the postgres docs: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-explain.html

There is also: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Image:Explaining_EXPLAIN.pdf which is a bit more in depth.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Mainly the link because I never really understood the `EXPLAIN` outputs...